# Table View not showing the Cells Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, swift3

I have created a Restaurant class and made all the connections to display the cells but when i hit run , it doesn't show the all the outlets that i have created.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class RestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var restaurants:[Resturant] = [
        Resturant(name: "Hardees", type: "Burger", location: "Many", image: "Hardees.jpg", isVisited: false), Resturant(name: "Shake Shack", type: "Burger", location: "Gulf Mall", image: "shakeshack.jpg", isVisited: false), Resturant(name: "Burgery", type: "Burger", location: "Gulf Mall", image: "shakeshack.jpg", isVisited: false), Resturant(name: "Dairy Queen", type: "Burger", location: "Gulf Mall", image: "shakeshack.jpg", isVisited: false), Resturant(name: "Elevation Burger", type: "Burger", location: "Gulf Mall", image: "shakeshack.jpg", isVisited: false), Resturant(name: "Fat Burger", type: "Burger", location: "Gulf Mall", image: "shakeshack.jpg", isVisited: false)
    ]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return restaurants.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.nameLabel.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].name
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurants[indexPath.row].image)
        cell.locationLabel.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].location
        cell.typeLabel.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].type

        cell.accessoryType = restaurants[indexPath.row].isVisited ? .checkmark : .none

        return cell
    }




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            restaurants.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        // Social Sharing Button
        let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Share", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

            let defaultText = "Just checking in at " + self.restaurants[indexPath.row].name

            if let imageToShare = UIImage(named: self.restaurants[indexPath.row].image) {
                let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [defaultText, imageToShare], applicationActivities: nil)
                self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })

        // Delete button
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Delete",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

            // Delete the row from the data source
            self.restaurants.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        })

        shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 48.0/255.0, green: 173.0/255.0, blue: 99.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 202.0/255.0, green: 202.0/255.0, blue: 203.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        return [deleteAction, shareAction]
    }

    // MARK: -

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showRestaurantDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let destinationController = segue.destination as! ResturantDetailViewController
                destinationController.resturant = restaurants[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here's my githu repo

[my github repo](https://github.com/Ahmedalthani/Burger-Land)

Comment: Did you set TableView delegate? if run in debug, is code into cellForRowAt indexPath executed?

Comment: tableView.reloadData() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Storyboard you are linking the "Burger restaurant" table controller to:

```
ResturantTableTableViewController
```

Just like your file "ResturantTableTableViewController.swift", but inside this file, you have declared it as:

```
class RestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController {
```

The storyboard ignores the file-name, but uses the name you have declared inside the file.

Change the file-name and link storyboard to the same class. Or you can change the class-name inside the "ResturantTableTableViewController.swift" file to the same as the file name ("ResturantTableTableViewController").

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey I figured out your issue, in interface builder you have set the custom class to an `RestaurantTableTableView` when you need to set it to you actual file name of `RestaurantTableViewController`.